# Как создать блоки в модальном окне?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fancybox

У меня есть галерея картинок в модальном окне, под каждой из них нужно вставить описание(не короткое), на сайте который я взял в пример картинку и описание взяли по моему в блок div, как мне сделать так же? Прошу объяснить по понятнее так как я совсем новичок в js.

Сайт с которого я слизываю дизайн, точнее шаблон от wix.com:
http://ru.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1642?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fru.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fall%2F2&bookName=&galleryDocIndex=7&category=all

Во вкладке О нас, внизу страницы есть фотографии сотрудников, при их нажатии они выходят в модальном окне, под ними есть текст, а как мне сделать такое же у себя? Можете привести хотя бы код для создания и отображения дивов, или как это ещё сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Внимательней читайте документацию к библиотеке. Там есть пример реализации:
http://jsfiddle.net/cWNw9/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
      beforeLoad: function() {
        var el, id = $(this.element).data('title-id');

        if (id) {
          el = $('#' + id);

          if (el.length) {
            this.title = el.html();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.fancybox-title a {
  color: #fff;
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="fancybox" data-title-id="title-1" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">
  <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<div id="title-1" class="hidden">
  This is 1st title. <a href="http://google.com">Some link</a>
</div>

<a class="fancybox" data-title-id="title-2" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg">
  <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt="" />
</a>

<div id="title-2" class="hidden">
  This is <b>2nd title</b>. <a href="http://google.com">Some link</a>
</div>
```